# JSR-356 javax websockets in Jetty (embedded and not)

Tags: java, xml, websocket, jetty, jsr356

#### Given that:

I'd like to deploy webapp, packaged as WAR having `web.xml` in it, to Jetty server.

Within that app, I'd like to be able to have a JSR-356 specified javax websocket endpoints configured. I prefer, that those endpoints to be provided via `ServerEndpointConfig`, **not** an annotation scan.

There are many resources exemplifying that with an embedded Jetty, utilizing already famous `WebSocketServerContainerInitializer.configureContext(context);` API. I can't do that, obviously.

There are others, jumping directly to `ServletContextListener` and obtaining the `ServerContainer` via famous `context.getAttribute("javax.websocket.server.ServerContainer"`). So far I'm getting pretty much `NULL` via this API, so obviously container is not added.

#### Question:

What is that bit of configuration that is missing? Can it be done, preferably, via `web.xml`? If it is about config files like `jetty.xml` or `jetty.ini` - example would be nice, again, preferably for `xml` syntax.

#### Update:

As per answer below (the accepted one) and as I've actually tried to describe here - the known way of configuration is **absolutely** working just fine. Saying known I mean either by adding `--module=websocket` to some `*.ini` file for a non-embedded Jetty, or by calling `WebSocketServerContainerInitializer.configureContext` for an embedded one.

So rephrasing the question: is there any experience/knowledge from someone to enable websocket module by purely `XML` based configuration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If using the `${jetty.base}` and `${jetty.home}` [recommended installation process for Standalone Jetty](https://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/current/startup-base-and-home.html), you should go to your `${jetty.base}` instance directory and enable the `websocket` module.

```
$ cd /path/to/mybase
$ java -jar /opt/jetty/jetty-home-9.4.14.v20181114/start.jar --add-to-start=websocket
$ grep "websocket" start.ini
--module=websocket
```

Now you have websocket enabled for that `${jetty.base}` instance.

If you want Jetty to discover your Server WebSocket endpoints via bytecode scanning your deployed webapps for annotations, then you'll also want the `annotations` module.

```
$ cd /path/to/mybase
$ java -jar /opt/jetty/jetty-home-9.4.14.v20181114/start.jar --add-to-start=annotations
$ grep "annotations" start.ini
--module=annotations
```

Once that's complete, you can do one (or more) of the following to have the websocket server endpoints deployed with your webapp.

- Simply annotate your class with [`@ServerEndpoint`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/websocket/server/ServerEndpoint.html) (from `javax.websocket.server.ServerEndpoint`)
- Or if you want to programmatically add WebSocket Server Endpoints, you have 2 options.

  1. Provide an implementation of [`javax.websocket.server.ServerApplicationConfig`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/websocket/server/ServerApplicationConfig.html) in your project and return the Server endpoints you want Jetty to deploy.
  2. During WebApp startup/initialization obtain the [`javax.websocket.server.ServerContainer`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/websocket/server/ServerContainer.html) from the `ServletContext.getAttribute("javax.websocket.server.ServerContainer")` and use it's `addEndpoint()` methods.   Note that this is only possible from either a [`ServletContextListener.contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent sce)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/ServletContextListener.html#contextInitialized-javax.servlet.ServletContextEvent-) or [`ServletContainerInitializer.onStartup(Set<Class<?>> c, ServletContext ctx)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/ServletContainerInitializer.html#onStartup-java.util.Set-javax.servlet.ServletContext-)

Why does this work in standalone Jetty?  What is standalone Jetty doing to make this possible?

The following happens:

- The [`websocket` module](https://github.com/eclipse/jetty.project/blob/jetty-9.4.14.v20181114/jetty-websocket/javax-websocket-server-impl/src/main/config/modules/websocket.mod) adds the `lib/websocket/*.jar` to the server classpath
- The `websocket` module depends on both `client` and `annotations` modules
- The [`client` module](https://github.com/eclipse/jetty.project/blob/jetty-9.4.14.v20181114/jetty-client/src/main/config/modules/client.mod) adds `lib/jetty-client-<jetty.version>.jar` to the server classpath
- The [`annotations` module](https://github.com/eclipse/jetty.project/blob/jetty-9.4.14.v20181114/jetty-annotations/src/main/config/modules/annotations.mod) adds `lib/jetty-annotations-<jetty.version>.jar` and `lib/annotations/*.jar` to the server classpath
- The `annotations` module depends on the `plus` module
- The `annotations` module selects [`etc/jetty-annotations.xml`](https://github.com/eclipse/jetty.project/blob/jetty-9.4.14.v20181114/jetty-annotations/src/main/config/etc/jetty-annotations.xml) for execution on startup
- The `annotations` module adds JPMS modules by name `org.objectweb.asm`
- The [`plus` module](https://github.com/eclipse/jetty.project/blob/jetty-9.4.14.v20181114/jetty-plus/src/main/plus-config/modules/plus.mod) adds `lib/jetty-plus-<jetty.version>.jar` to the server classpath
- The `plus` module selects [`etc/jetty-plus.xml`](https://github.com/eclipse/jetty.project/blob/jetty-9.4.14.v20181114/jetty-plus/src/main/plus-config/etc/jetty-plus.xml) for execution on startup
- The `plus` module depends on the `server`, `security`, `jndi`, `webapp`, and `transactions` modules

(I'll skip the rest of the modules that are selected this way)

In short, with just adding `websocket` module you gain the following server classpath entries

```
lib/websocket/*.jar
lib/jetty-client-<jetty.version>.jar
lib/jetty-annotations-<jetty.version>.jar
lib/annotations/*.jar
lib/jetty-plus-<jetty.version>.jar
```

And the following XML files

```
lib/jetty-annotations.xml
lib/jetty-plus.xml
```

Both of these XML files simply modify the default `Configuration` list on the server side, making the `Configuration` behavior they introduce available to all deployed WebApps.

You can alternatively [set the `Configuration` on the `WebAppContext`](https://www.eclipse.org/jetty/javadoc/current/org/eclipse/jetty/webapp/WebAppContext.html#setConfigurationClasses-java.lang.String:A-) (before it's started) for webapp specific behaviors.

Example:

```java
WebAppContext context = new WebAppContext();
context.setContextPath("/");
context.setBaseResource(Resource.newResource(rootResourceUrl));

context.setConfigurations(new Configuration[] {
            new AnnotationConfiguration(),
            new WebXmlConfiguration(),
            new WebInfConfiguration(),
            new PlusConfiguration(), 
            new MetaInfConfiguration(),
            new FragmentConfiguration(), 
            new EnvConfiguration()});    

handlerList.addHandler(context);
```

> Note: for `javax.websocket` you *must* use a `WebAppContext`, as the behaviors defined for its initialization require a full Web App to function.
>   While you can use a `ServletContextHandler` with `javax.websocket` endpoints, this style is 100% manually defined, intialized, and declared, with no automatic bytecode / annotation scanning features that JSR-356 relies on.

You can see all of this from the command line too.

Show the active `${jetty.base}` configuration, what the XML property values are, what the server classpath is, and what XML is going to be executed (and in what order!!)

```
$ cd /path/to/mybase
$ java -jar /opt/jetty/jetty-home-9.4.14.v20181114/start.jar --list-config
```

Show the list of modules and how they relate (along with which ones are selected in your `${jetty.base}` configuration)

```
$ cd /path/to/mybase
$ java -jar /opt/jetty/jetty-home-9.4.14.v20181114/start.jar --list-modules
```

Comment: As it is stated in my question, the path you outline here is known **and working** to me (both, `--module=websocket` and some flavor of `WebSocketServerContainerInitializer.configureContext(context)`. Too bad my case is more difficult: it is somewhat historically given to me deployment where **embedded** Jetty is configured from Java to read **XML** files and be configured by them. Any suggestion for that?

Comment: "Modules" are a purely standalone Jetty concept in Jetty 9.x.  "Modules" for embedded-jetty are being introduced in Jetty 10.x, but as formal JPMS Modules.

Comment: Thanks for this approval of what seemingly was not possible (Jetty 9.4..). Well, looks like I'm going to give up on JAVAX way and do the WebSockets 'Jetty' way (servlet etc).

Comment: You can still do the [inferior javax way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25770789/jetty-websocket-api-vs-the-standard-jsr-356-api) if you want, you just have to declare the Server `Configuration` before you start the `WebAppContext` for your JSR-356 (`javax.websocket`) behaviors.  Note: you must use a `WebAppContext`, not a `ServletContextHandler`.